# How to show that if $ p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$ then there exists a $u,v \in \mathbb Z: u^2 + 2v^2 = p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

I'm trying to show this statement:

$$p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8, \; \; \exists \; u,v \in \mathbb Z : u^2 + 2 v^2 = p.$$

I believed I proved it the other direction using the ring $\mathbb Z{\sqrt{-2}}$. This is my reasoning so far: Suppose that $-2 \equiv x^2 \pmod p$ then $p$ divides $x^2 + 2 = (x - i\sqrt{2})(x + i\sqrt{2})$. This shows that $p$ is not a prime, that is $p = mn $. Taking the norms, we get $N(p) = N(m)N(n) = x^2 + 2y^2$ We can see that $p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$. How do I prove using the forward direction?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685958/let-p-be-prime-and-frac-3p-1-prove-that-p-is-of-the-form-p-a23b2/685983#685983 -- will this help ??

Comment: user129017 I am taking a class that only assumes that you've taken 1 calculus and 1 linear algebra course. The number theory is being introduced under the context of writing expository proofs. I am familiar with Legendre's symbol but not all of its properties and I have no idea what a lattice is.

Comment: what about Jack D'Aurizio's proof ? It only uses fermat's descent (Elementary-Numbertheory)

Answer (score 1):

As this has class number one there are many approaches. Solve
$$ \beta^2 \equiv -8 \pmod p.  $$ If your $\beta$ is odd, replace by $p-\beta$ which is even, anyway call it $b.$ Now you have
$$ b^2 \equiv -8 \pmod {4p}  $$ with $b$ even, or
$$ b^2 - 4pt = -8.  $$
So, the binary quadratic form 
$$  \langle p,b,t \rangle  $$  or
$$  f(x,y) = p x^2 + b x y + t y^2  $$ has discriminant $-8.$ Gauss reduce this, the result is  $$  \langle 1,0,2 \rangle  $$ because that is the only reduced form for that discriminant.

ALMOST DONE

So, reduction: there is a 2 by 2 matrix with determinant 1, write it as
$$  P = \; 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  \alpha &  \beta   \\
   \gamma & \delta     
\end{array} 
  \right),  $$
also name
$$  M = \; 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  p & b/2   \\
   b/2 & t     
\end{array} 
  \right),  $$
and
$$  R = \; 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  1 & 0   \\
   0 & 2     
\end{array} 
  \right).  $$

The relationship found by doing reduction step by step is 
$$ P^T M P = R.  $$

Let $Q = P^{-1}.$ Then
$$ Q^T R Q = M.  $$

The left-hand column of $Q$ gives the representation of your original prime $p.$ Multiply it out.