# Euler's proof of $3m+1\in \mathbb{P}\implies 3m+1=x^2+3y^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

as the title suggests I am looking for Euler's descent proof of the fact that all primes of the form $3m+1$ can be represented as $x^2+3y^2$.

Note: I am not interested in any other proofs but Euler's one.

Thanks!

EDIT: This isn't a duplicate, I am specifically asking for Euler's proof using Fermat's descent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let $p$ be prime and $(\frac{-3}p)=1$. Prove that $p$ is of the form $p=a^2+3b^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685958/let-p-be-prime-and-frac-3p-1-prove-that-p-is-of-the-form-p-a23b2)

Comment: That was Euler's proof (look at the descent part).

Comment: The basic step of the descent is: there exists some $c$ such that $c^2+3=k\cdot p$, so you first have to prove that $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ implies that $-3$ is a square $\pmod{p}$. I proved that in a completely elementary way: just the Cauchy's theorem for groups.