# For which primes $p$ does $x^2\equiv3\pmod{p}$ have a solution?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

attempt at solution:  using Legendre symbol, what I did was notice that the equation has a solution if ($3/p$)=1 IFF ($p/3$)x(-1)^(p-1)/2 = 1

So, can I say that p has to satisfy two properties (4 cases)?  For example, case 1 is:
      If p≡1 mod3, then ($p/3$)=1, then we have a solution IFF p≡1 mod4

Comment: The statement "the equation has a solution if... iff..." is a little unclear. Can you please rephrase that?

Comment: You're on the right track. But you can put your conclusion in a nicer form by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

In [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685958/let-p-be-prime-and-frac-3p-1-prove-that-p-is-of-the-form-p-a23b2) I proved that for every prime $p>3$, $-3$ is a quadratic residue **iff** $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ by using only the Cauchy theorem for groups. Since for every odd prime we know that $-1$ is a quadratic residue **iff** $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and:
$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right),$$
it follows that $3$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ **iff** $\color{blue}{p\equiv\pm 1\pmod{12}}$.