# Describe the rational points on $3x^2 + y^2 = 4$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, rational-numbers

Apart from $(x, y) = (0, 2)$ and $(1, 1)$, are there any nonzero rational points on the curve $3x^2 + y^2 = 4$ ?

Comment: The question should be "describe the rational points on the curve" to avoid "trivial answer"

Comment: i guess it would be a good start to describe the rational points on $3x^2+y^2=4$, then place the restriction of $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not concerned with the cases $n=1$ or $2$?

Comment: @Cataline, thank you for your suggestion, i have since edited it to that form

Comment: @Isaac., did you mean to drop the $n$ from $x^{2n}$?

Comment: homogenize, find intersection point of the tangents and $(0,2,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ transform into a parabola, find rational point there, retransform backward.

Comment: @Barry, yes indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Let $y=mx+2$ be the equation of a line with *rational* slope $m$.  It intersects the ellipse $3x^2+y^2=4$ at the rational point $(0,2)$.  Consequently it's other point of intersection will also be rational.

Conversely, if $(a,b)\not=(0,\pm2)$ is a rational point on the ellipse, the line between it and $(0,2)$ has rational slope $m=(b-2)/a$. (You can even allow $(a,b)=(0,-2)$ if you think of the vertical line $x=0$ as having "rational slope $\pm\infty$.")

Comment: Thanks Barry for your response. Now, let us bring back our additional restriction that $n\geq 3$.

Comment: @Isaac., if you want to bring back the restriction, please do it as a *new* question.  (You can refer to this one if you like, but it's preferable not to change a question once it's been answered.)  Also, I still wonder why you want to jump over the case $n=2$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for instance, $(\frac87,\frac27)$.

Here’s the general principle: if a conic has *one* rational point $P$, you can look at the pencil of lines through $P$ and see where each intersects your curve. A conic over $\Bbb Q$ and a line defined over $\Bbb Q$ have two points in common always, and either they consist of a pair of $\Bbb Q$-conjugate points or they both are rational. Since $P$ is rational, the other is too. Now to work it out:

Take your point $P$ to be $(0,-2)$, and look at the line of slope $m$ passing through $P$, namely $Y=mX-2$, and intersect with your curve $3X^2+Y^2=4$:
\begin{align}
3X^2 + (mX-2)^2&=4\\
3X^2+m^2X^2-4mX&=0\\
(m^2+3)X^2&=4mX\quad\text{(exclude $X=0$)}\\
X&=\frac{4m}{m^2+3}\\
Y&=m\frac{4m}{m^2+3}-2=\frac{2m^2-6}{m^2+3}\,,
\end{align}
and any rational value of $m$ gives you a rational point on your curve. I took $m=2$ to get the point I quoted above.

Comment: than you for your response. However, the original question was about equation $y^2 = 4 - 3x^{2n}$, where $n\geq 3$ is an integer.

Comment: Good luck with that, then: I answered the question I saw. The curve $y^2=4-3x^4$ is already an Elliptic Curve, and curves of this type have been the life work of mathematicians for the last 75 years.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here's a way to construct some: take any prime $p\equiv1\pmod3$ and write it in the form $a^2+3b^2$ (this is always possible, see below). Then a case of the generalized [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) gives
$$p^2=3\cdot(2ab)^2+(a^2-3b^2)^2$$
$$4p^2=3\cdot(a^2+2ab-3b^2)^2+(a^2-6ab-3b^2)^2,$$

so a possible non-trivial solution is
$$3\left(\frac{a^2+2ab-3b^2}{a^2+3b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a^2-6ab-3b^2}{a^2+3b^2}\right)^2=4.$$

In fact, the above formula gives you an entire family of solutions, just pick any $a,b\in\Bbb Z\;$! It's nice though to see some number theory telling what kind of solutions we may expect to come out of that formula.

**Example.** $37\equiv1\pmod3$. We find $37=5^2+3\cdot2^2$, so one solution is

$$3\left(\frac{5^2+20-3\cdot2^2}{37}\right)^2+\left(\frac{5^2-60-3\cdot2^2}{37}\right)^2=4,$$
that is, $$3\cdot\left(\frac{33}{37}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-47}{37}\right)^2=4$$
*(And you can ignore the minus sign, of course.)*

In fact we have:

> **Theorem.** $n\in\mathbb N$ is of the form $a^2+3b^2$ iff every prime divisor $p\equiv2\pmod3$ of $n$ comes with even exponent in the factorisation of $n$.

(For the hardest direction, see the beautiful descent proof at [Let $p$ be prime and $(\frac{-3}p)=1$. Prove that $p$ is of the form $p=a^2+3b^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685958).)
What's most interesting here is that there's also a way to construct non-trivial solutions, the so-called generalized [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity):
$$\left(a^2 + 3b^2\right)\left(c^2 + 3d^2\right) = \left(ac-3bd\right)^2 + 3\left(ad+bc\right)^2.$$

Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be an integer that is non-trivially representable as $a^2+3b^2$. Then the above identity gives $$n^2=(a^2-3b^2)^2+3\cdot(2ab)^2$$
$$4n^2=(a^2-6ab-3b^2)^2+3\cdot(a^2+2ab-3b^2),$$
so we've got a rational solution to $3x^2+y^2=4$.

Of course, we could also simply have taken $4n^2=(2a^2-6b^2)^2+3\cdot(4ab)^2$, but as you can see the Brahmagupta-identity gives more possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just give the final result for @Barry Cipra:'s answer:

Taking the line $y = - m x + 2$ passing through the point $(0,2)$ of the curve, the other intersection point with the curve is 
\begin{eqnarray}
x &= &\frac{4 m}{3 + m^2} \\
y &= & \frac{ 2 ( 3 - m^2)}{3+m^2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

There is a viewpoint initiated in Fricke and Klein (1897), especially pages 507-508, and reported in [Theorem I.9 on page 15 of PLESKEN](https://books.google.com/books?id=4TAxOSzxODUC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Let%20g%20be%20an%20integral%20ternary%20quadratic%20form,%20which%20is%20indefinite%20and%20nondegenerate&source=bl&ots=ETCH01cGlX&sig=kx0OSGeCR185rDg_f0N4DWG_ewU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYlMTgn_XJAhUWwWMKHTjqDXUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Let%20g%20be%20an%20integral%20ternary%20quadratic%20form%2C%20which%20is%20indefinite%20and%20nondegenerate&f=false). It is rigid as to dimensions: given an isotropic (over $\mathbb Q$ and therefore $\mathbb Z$) ternary quadratic form, it parametrizes all integer primitive solutions by one or more triples of binary quadratic forms.

The outcome is that every **primitive** integer solution to
$$ 3x^2 + y^2 = 4 z^2   $$ can be written with $\gcd(u,v) = 1$ and $u \neq v \pmod 3$ as
$$ x = u^2 + 2 u v, \; \; y = -u^2 + 2 u v + 2 v^2, \; \; z = u^2 + uv + v^2. $$
Here $z > 0,$ we may choose $\pm x$ but we do not get to choose the sign of $y.$

For your other question, you want $x/z = (s/t)^n$ for $n \geq 3.$ My first impression is that this means
$$ u^2 + 2 u v = s^n, \; \; \;  u^2 + u v + v^2 = t^n.    $$
Either one can be accomplished alone, I don't see doing them simultaneously.

For the curious, the matrix identity guaranteed by the theorem in Plesken is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -4
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = 
-12
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

Comment: The other question is asked here (but put on hold for the moment): [Describe the rational points on $y^2 = 4 - 3x^{2n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587211)

Comment: @barto thanks. I put part of an answer there but deleted it ( I had not yet proved I had all primitive integer solutions), then the question was closed. If I finished that question it would let me edit that and undelete, but I'm not sure anyone would notice.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve $x^2+3y^2=4z^2$ in integers. Let wlog $\gcd(y,z)=\gcd(z,x)=1$.

If $\gcd(x,y)=2$, then let $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$. Then $x_1^2+3y_1^2=z^2$, so $3y_1^2=(z+x_1)(z-x_1)$, so $\gcd(z+x_1,z-x_1)=1$, so two cases:

$1)\ $ $z+x_1=\pm 3a^2$, $z-x_1=\pm b^2$. Then $x_1=\pm \frac{3a^2-b^2}{2}$, $z=\pm\frac{3a^2+b^2}{2}$, so $y=\pm 2ab$.

$2)\ $ $z+x_1=\pm b^2$, $z-x_1=\pm 3a^2$. Then $x_1=\pm\frac{b^2-3a^2}{2}$, $z=\pm \frac{3a^2+b^2}{2}$, so $y=\pm 2ab$.

So if $\gcd(x,y)=2$, then all the solutions are given by $(x,y,z)=\left(\pm \left(b^2-3a^2\right), \pm 2ab, \pm\frac{3a^2+b^2}{2}\right)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$.

If $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $3y^2=(2z-x)(2z+x)$ and $\gcd(2z-x,2z+x)=1$. Two cases:

$1)\ $ $2z-x=\pm 3a^2$, $2z+x=\pm b^2$. Then $x=\pm\frac{b^2-3a^2}{2}$, $z=\pm \frac{b^2+3a^2}{4}$, so $y=\pm ab$.

$2)\ $ $2z-x=\pm b^2$, $2z+x=\pm 3a^2$. Then $x=\pm \frac{3a^2-b^2}{2}$, $z=\pm \frac{b^2+3a^2}{4}$, so $y=\pm ab$.

So if $\gcd(x,y)=1$, all the solutions are given by $(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\frac{b^2-3a^2}{2},\pm ab,\pm \frac{b^2+3a^2}{4}\right)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$.

If $x^2+3y^2=4$ for rational $x,y$, then let $(x,y)=(p/q,r/s)$ with $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb Z$, $qs\neq 0$.

Then $p^2+3r^2=4(qs)^2$, so either $(p,r,qs)=\left(\pm \left(b^2-3a^2\right), \pm ab, \pm\frac{3a^2+b^2}{2}\right)$ or $(p,r,qs)=\left(\pm\frac{b^2-3a^2}{2},\pm ab,\pm \frac{b^2+3a^2}{4}\right)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$, $a,b$ not both $0$.

$(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac{b^2-3a^2}{2q},\pm \frac{b^2+3a^2}{4s}\right)$ with $qs=\frac{b^2+3a^2}{4}$ and $a,b,q,s\in\mathbb Z$, $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$, $a,b$ not both $0$ classifies all the solutions.