# A quadratic residue question

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p>3$ be a prime number. Is it true that 
$$
\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=
\begin{cases}
  1 & p\equiv1(\bmod{\,3})\\
  -1 & p\equiv-1(\bmod{\,3})\\
\end{cases}\quad?
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/685982/44121

Comment: Thanks @Jack D'Aurizio !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  quadratic reciprocity $$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)&=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)  \\
&=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) \\ 
&= \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
And it's easy to check that squares are $\equiv 1\bmod{3}$.

Comment: That is correct but I think that the interesting part comes from proving such result without resorting to the full power of quadratic reciprocity. Indeed, Cauchy and Lagrange's theorems do the job pretty nicely.

Comment: Agreed and your post strikes a nice balance between being complete and not overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 5):

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, by Cauchy's theorem there is an order-$3$ element of $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$. 
If we call such element $\omega$, we have $\omega^3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $\omega\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, hence
$$ \omega^2+\omega+1 \equiv 0\pmod{p} \tag{1}$$
$$ 4\omega^2+4\omega+1 \equiv -3\pmod{p} \tag{2}$$
$$ (2\omega+1)^2 \equiv -3\pmod{p}\tag{3} $$
and $-3$ is a quadratic residue. Conversely, if $-3$ is a quadratic residue for some prime $p>3$, there must be an order-$3$ element of $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$, hence $3\mid(p-1)$ by Lagrange's theorem and $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Which way are you deducing that an order $3$ element exists if $-3$ is a quadratic residue?

Comment: @BillDubuque: by following the inverse path $(3)\mapsto(2)\mapsto(1)$. If $a^2\equiv -3$, then $\frac{a-1}{2}$ is a root of $x^2+x+1=0$, hence an order-$3$ element.