# how to show $x^2+3y^2=n$ has an integral solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone tell me how to show $x^2+3y^2=n$ has an integral solution iff the prime factor of $n$ which are of the form $3k-1$ has even exponents?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, do you know the Legendre symbol and quadratic reciprocity???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Comment: The key idea is that $\,x^2+3y^2=(x+\sqrt{-3}y)(x-\sqrt-{3}y)\,$ and you factor elements in the ring of "numbers" the form $\,x+\sqrt{-3}y.\,$ This is similar to the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer).

Comment: Every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ can be written as $x^2+3y^2$ (proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2300356/44121) and since $(x^2+3y^2)(X^2+3Y^2)=(xX+3yY)^2+3(Xy-Yx)^2$ every number with prime factors of the form $3k+1$ can be written as $x^2+3y^2$. If $x$ and $y$ are coprime and we assume that $p=3k-1$ is a divisor of $n=x^2+3y^2$, we get that $z^2+3\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has a solution, which is absurd since $-3$ is a non-quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$.